# What type of lens will auto-focus on Nikon bodies without a focus motor?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, nikon-d40

I know my D40 doesn't have a motor in it to auto-focus lenses.

What type of lens has the motor in it? How can I know which lenses will and will not work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Nikon with AF-I and AF-S
- Sigma with HSM (and older ones that
  list as "with motor for Nikon" or the
  like obviously)
- Tamron with USD (and older ones that
  list as "with motor for Nikon" or the
  like obviously)
- Tokina lenses specifically listing "built-in AF motor drive" as a feature

Answer (score 3):

As you note, the D40 doesn't have an autofocus motor.  Nikon's designation for the lenses that have the motor include the **AF-I** and **AF-S** lines.

Answer (score -1):

Nikon Lenses with the designation AI, AI-S, AF will not work on your camera. Lens zCodes can be found here:

http://www.dslrgeeks.com/forum/showthread.php?t=4