# Will any of my old Nikon gear be compatible with a D3100?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, compatibility

I have an old Nikon F801 35mm film camera with a Nikon SB-24 flash gun a AF Nikkor 70-210 mm 1:3.3-4-5 & a AF Nikkor 35-70mm 1:3.3-4.5

I am thinking of buying a new set up the Nikon D3100 with 18-55mm VR Lens will anything be compatible with the new set up. Thanks.

Comment: Nikon's web-site has a [D3100 Lens Compatibiity](http://imaging.nikon.com/products/imaging/lineup/digitalcamera/slr/d3100/compatibility02.htm) page which provides this information

Answer (score 4):

The lenses will fit but will **not autofocus** as the D3100 does not have an in-camera focus motor and requires **AF-S lenses** for auto focus.

If you wish to use AF with your lenses, then you should consider the D7000 or a **model with 1 to 3 numbers in its name** (D300S, D700, D90, D3S, etc).

Note that the angle-of-view of your lenses will be different if you do not go with a full-frame body (D3S, D3X or D700). So a 70-210mm lens will give you the equivalent angle-of-view of a 105-315mm lens on your film camera. You have to multiple by 1.5 which is called the focal-length multiplier.

The flash will probably work, but I'm just guessing!

Comment: Thanks for the comments might be worth paying a bit more for the D90

Comment: I don't believe the D40 has a focus motor.  Granted the D40 is no longer in production...

Comment: Yes, the D40, D40X and D60 did not have focus motors either.

Comment: Speaking of old lenses, AF-I [would also auto focus](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/4039/what-type-of-lens-will-auto-focus-on-nikon-bodies-without-a-focus-motor) in addition to AF-S.

Answer (score 3):

The SB-24 will fire but you will not be able to use the TTL-mode. Nikon changed their flash exposure protocol when they introduced the latest DSLRs.

A (auto) mode will work fine, as will M (manual).

Comment: Thanks will stick with buying the Nikon D3100 see how I go on

Answer (score 2):

All your stuff should be compatible in that it will allow you to take pictures and should meter correctly.  However, the D3100 lacks an in body focus motor and will not autofocus your two older lenses.  If that's important to you, consider the D90 or D7000 which have the required in body motor.

Comment: Thanks for the comments would sell them and put the money to a new lens but you don't get offered much now

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford it, I'd go for the D7000. It has great specs and you will be able to use all your AF lenses too. Although the D3100 is a great camera, my son has just purchased one an it's awesome. However, good lenses are what really counts in photo taking. Keep and use your old lenses to their full potential.

Comment: Thanks i've been looking at the D7000 to expensive for me at tne moment will just have to use manual focus thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1):

Please see the compatibility table at site

https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/886/~/d-slr-and-nikon-speedlight-compatibility