# Will a AF VR_Nikkor 80-400mm 1:4.5-5.6D lens work on a Nikon D3400?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus

I have a AF VR_Nikkor 80-400mm 1:4.5-5.6D that I use with my Nikon carmera. I am looking at purchasing a Nikon D3400. Will this lens work on the D3400?

Comment: Also see [What type of lens will auto-focus on Nikon bodies without a focus motor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/what-type-of-lens-will-auto-focus-on-nikon-bodies-without-a-focus-motor)

Answer (score 4):

You can use it to take pictures with a D3400, but you will need to manually focus the lens.

Nikon AF lenses do not have focusing motors in the lens and depend on a focusing motor in the camera body. The D3x00 and D5x00 series cameras do not feature an in-body AF motor. AF-S lenses, which do have a focusing motor in the lens, are needed to use autofocus with the D3x00and D5x00 bodies.

There is a newer version, the AF-S Nikkor 80-400mm f/4.5-5.6 G ED VR, that will autofocus with a D3400.